# Is there a way to print the output of subprocess without the newline and other redundant characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Let's say I have this short script here:

```
import subprocess

some = subprocess.run("ls", shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(some.stdout)
```

When I print out the output with the last statement, I get this:

```
b'main.py\nprogram.cpp\nreadme.txt\nsomefile.c\n'
```

Does anyone know a way to print the same output without the **letter b, single quotes, backslash, and newline character?** and separate each file/directory with an "Invisible" newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you receive `bytes` instead of a string. You could check that by printing `type(some.stdout)`. So you need to decode that `bytes` into string, by using [method of the same name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode). Something like this:

```
print(some.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```